Including 'guides = collect' causes patchwork to return error message 'Error in as.unit(value) : object is not coercible to a unit'
A new error message popped up with patchwork today in code that used to work.
Here's a reproducible example:
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(patchwork)

d1 <- tibble(
  x = rep(1, 5),
  y = rep(1, 5),
  col = letters[1:5]
)

p1 <- ggplot(
  aes(
    x, y, color = col
  ),
  data = d1 %>% 
    slice(1:3)
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~col, nrow = 1) +
  geom_point(
    size = 5
  ) 

p2 <- ggplot(
  aes(
    x, y, color = col
  ),
  data = d1 %>% 
    slice(4:5)
) +
  facet_wrap(~col, nrow = 1) +
  geom_point(
    size = 5
  )


p1 / p2 +
  plot_layout(
    design = "
    111
    22#
    ")

This generates the following figure

But if we specify guides = collect like this:
p1 / p2 +
  plot_layout(
    design = "
    111
    22#
    ", 
    guides = "collect"
    )

I receive this error
Error in as.unit(value) : object is not coercible to a unit
Here's my sessionInfo()
R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 26120)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

time zone: Australia/Sydney
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] patchwork_1.2.0      magrittr_2.0.3       lubridate_1.9.3      forcats_1.0.0        stringr_1.5.1.9000  
 [6] dplyr_1.1.4          purrr_1.0.2.9000     readr_2.1.5          tidyr_1.3.1          tibble_3.2.1        
[11] ggplot2_3.5.1.9000   tidyverse_2.0.0.9000

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] vctrs_0.6.5       cli_3.6.3         rlang_1.1.4       stringi_1.8.4     generics_0.1.3   
 [6] labeling_0.4.3    glue_1.7.0        colorspace_2.1-1  hms_1.1.3         scales_1.3.0     
[11] fansi_1.0.6       grid_4.4.1        munsell_0.5.1     tzdb_0.4.0        lifecycle_1.0.4  
[16] compiler_4.4.1    timechange_0.3.0  pkgconfig_2.0.3   rstudioapi_0.16.0 farver_2.1.2     
[21] R6_2.5.1          tidyselect_1.2.1  utf8_1.2.4        pillar_1.9.0      tools_4.4.1      
[26] withr_3.0.1       gtable_0.3.5     


This issue is related to the dev version 3.5.1.9000 of ggplot2 you are using. The code works fine using the CRAN version 3.5.1 of ggplot2.

Oh great! Always nice to find a real bug!

The issue is fixed in the dev version of patchwork. See https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork/issues/374
